# How to disable visual studio intellisense just in SQL Query?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, red-gate-sql-prompt

I have a redgate [sql prompt] extention intellisense on visual studio 2013 ,when I am type in SQL Query the two intellisense appear see the below Image , So I want to disable the visual studio intellisense Just in SQL Query [Not in all visual studio ]

[image: intellisense issue]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just go to:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> SQL Server Tools -> IntelliSense
```

Uncheck "Enable IntelliSense"

I hope to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**If anybody is in SQL server management studio like me this is where to turn this off in there:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.9.6 it's:

- `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `SQL Server Tools` -> `Statement completion`
- **Uncheck** `Auto list members`

[image]